# jQuery on TAB pressure simulate on(mousedown) event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, keydown

In my webpage i have to trap TAB key pressure and then simulate mousedown event for the object involved.
I tried so:

```
$('*').keydown(function(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

if (keyCode == 9) { 
    var elementClicked = e.target.nodeName;
    elementClicked.mousedown();
}
});
```

but error

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

on elementClicked.mousedown(); row appears.

How can i simulate and call the mousedown event on element involved in TAB pressure??

Thanks in advance

AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).trigger('mousedown')` or just `$(this).click()` and this will trigger whatever event is bound to that element. note that you should do `*`... that's super bad for performance.

### Try:

```
$(document).on('keydown.tab', '*', function(e){
  if( e.keyCode == 9 ){
    $(this).trigger('mousedown');
  }
  return false;
});
```

But you can't really know on which element was the TAB clicked...

### UPDATE:

you should first give all elements the attribute `tabindex`, only then those element could be tracked when pressing the tab key, because they have focus (by clicking on them first or focusing via keyboard) :

```
$('body *').each(function(i){
    this.setAttribute('tabindex',i);
});
```

### [DEMO PAGE](http://jsbin.com/jemiriyune/1/edit?html,js,output) - only the `h1` element simulates `click` using TAB

Answer (score 1):

`elementClicked` is an object name and not an object -
select object using jquery:

```
$(elementClicked).mousedown()
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try below updated code:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

    if (keyCode == 9) { 
        var elementClicked = $(this);
        elementClicked.trigger("mousedown");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!